# LXML/XPATH issue

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, lxml

I am trying to parse `http://biz.yahoo.com/research/earncal/20150806.html` with `lxml.xpath` and the following code.

```
master_tick = []

url = 'http://biz.yahoo.com/research/earncal/20150806.html'

resp = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(resp.text)

update_tick = [td.text_content() for td in tree.xpath("html/body/p[3]/table/tr[2]/td/table[1]/tr[2]/td[2]/a")]

master_tick.append(update_tick)

myfile = open('/home/a73nk-xce/Documents/Python/SharkFin/DAT/TICKER_LISTS/UpdateTick%s.csv' % today, 'w', newline='')
wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for eachrow in master_tick:
    wr.writerows([r] for r in eachrow)
```

There isn't a name or ID for the table and I want to pull all of the ticker symbols from the table and import them into a csv.  Any help?

Comment: Please describe the problem. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Even if I take the `csv` statement out and just use a simple print statement I am still getting an empty list.  The parsing function is not working properly due to a faulty `XPATH` is my best answer to that question

Comment: Try "html/body/p[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[0]/table[0]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a"

Comment: ...empty list, it's a mystery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There isn't a name or ID for the table and I want to pull all of the ticker symbols from the table

so I suggest you select the `tr` by its text content, and then select sibling rows (excluding the one with "Company", "Symbol", "Time", and "Conference Call" column headers)

This becomes:

```
url = 'http://biz.yahoo.com/research/earncal/20150806.html'

resp = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(resp.text)

update_tick = [td.text_content()
               for td in tree.xpath('''//tr[starts-with(normalize-space(.), "Earnings Announcements for")]
                                        /following-sibling::tr[position()>1]
                                        /td[2]/a')]

print update_tick

['TWOU', 'DDD', 'AAON', 'AXAS', 'ACAD', 'XLRN', '2353.TW', 'ACTA', 'AE', 'ADS.DE', 'ADI.V', 'AAV.TO', 'AMTX', 'WGA', 'AGK.L', 'AGIO', 'AL', 'AIRM', 'AYR', 'ALEX', 'ALXA', 'ALC.TO', 'ALSC3.SA', 'AGN', 'AIQ', 'ALQA', 'ALNY', 'AIF.TO', 'AMRN', 'AMBR', 'AMCX', 'AMH', 'AMIC', 'ASEI', 'ASYS', 'AMRS', 'ANAC', 'ANAD', 'APA', 'AINV', 'APLE', 'AQXP', 'PETX', 'ANET', 'ARTR3.SA', 'AHP', 'AHT', 'AINC', 'ASPN', 'AGO', 'ATRO', 'ATRA', 'ATHX', 'ATLS', 'ARP', 'ATOS', 'ABTL', 'ACQ.TO', 'AM.TO', 'AV.L', 'AXX.TO', 'AXGN', 'AZUR', 'BWINB', 'BTN', 'BMPS.MI', 'PMI.MI', 'BBX', 'BCE.TO', 'BECN', 'BEC.BK', 'BDX', 'BFCF', 'BR.TO', 'BBG', 'BIND', 'BIO', 'TECH', 'BLFS', 'BEAT', 'BITA', 'BIZIM.IS', 'BLUE', 'BTH', 'GBT.TO', 'WIFI', 'BDBD', 'BVX', 'BPOST.BR', 'BBEP', 'BNR.DE', 'EAT', 'BRS', 'BRKS', 'BBW', 'CCC', 'CTY.TO', 'CRC', 'CBL.TO', 'CNQ.TO', 'CAM.TO', 'CPST', 'CRDC', 'CECO', 'CRZO', '5264.TW', 'CECE', 'CDR', 'CENX', 'CCS', 'CERU', 'CERS', 'CTIP3.SA', 'CSG', 'CTHR', 'CEMI', 'CCXI', 'CC', 'CPK', 'CMRX', 'CXDC', 'CIX.TO', 'CNK', 'CTO.V', 'CIO', 'CDTI', 'CLRO', 'CLVS', 'COB.L', 'CCOI', 'CLNY', 'MOC', 'COP.DE', 'CFF.TO', 'CNXR', 'CNSL', 'ED', 'MCF', 'CNL.TO', 'CTB', 'CORE', 'CSOD', 'COVS', 'CR.TO', 'CYRX', 'CCLP', 'CTIC', 'CUBE', 'CUB', 'CRIS', 'CVT', 'CYTX', 'DMD', 'DPW.DE', 'DTE.DE', 'DXM', 'DRNA', 'DGLY', 'DIL.NZ', 'DIOD', 'DVCR', 'BAGR', 'DLHC', 'DMLP', 'HILL', 'DOW.AX', 'DRYS', 'DUE.DE', 'DUK', 'DYN', 'DX', 'DEA', 'ELON', 'EFH.TO', 'SATS', 'ESES', 'ECO.TO', 'EGLT', 'RDEN', 'EFC', 'ELRN.TA', 'EMCI', 'EMES', 'EBS', 'ENTA', 'EDR.TO', 'GI', 'EFX.TO', 'EGN', 'ENR', 'ERII', 'ENOC', 'EGL', 'ENG', 'ETM', 'ETRM', 'EGT', 'EVC', 'EOG', 'EPZM', 'EAC', 'ESPR', 'ESTC3.SA', 'ECT.AS', 'EVEN3.SA', '2393.TW', 'EVH', 'EXE.TO', 'EXTR', '3035.TW', 'FCSC', 'FDUS', 'FTT.TO', 'FAC', 'FSV.TO', 'FPRX', 'FLTX', 'FLXN', 'FLDM', '2707.TW', '6505.TW', 'FRA.DE', 'FRU.TO', 'FNTN.DE', 'FRE.DE', 'FRS', 'FSYS', 'FXEN', 'FXCM', 'GAIA', 'GCAP', 'GALE', 'GLOG', 'GST', 'GENL.L', 'GNRC', 'GAM', 'GEN', 'GNE', 'GNMK', 'GNCA', 'GEOS', 'ROCK', 'GEI.TO', '8406.TWO', 'GLA1V.HE', 'BRSS', 'ENT', 'GLP', 'GLYC', 'GOGO', 'AUMN', 'GSBD', 'GXP', 'GRPN', 'GGAL.BA', 'GSVC', 'GTT', 'GTXI', 'GWP.L', 'HGN.TO', 'HMPR', 'HASI', 'HNSN', 'HDNG', 'HAW.DE', 'HAYN', 'HL', 'HTO.AT', 'HTGC', 'HGG', 'HCLP', 'ONE', 'HBKA', 'HPTO', 'HMHC', 'HWCC', 'HRG', 'HSNI', '2498.TW', 'HUBS', 'HPP', 'HII', 'IEP', 'ICTV', 'IDRA', 'IGM.TO', 'IRG', 'IKAN', 'IKNX', 'IGD.MI', 'IMUC', 'IMH', 'IMPV', 'SAAS', 'ICD', 'IHC', 'INFI', 'IPCC', 'IFON', 'IRC', 'ISAT.L', 'INWK', 'INSM', 'INSY', 'IAM.TO', 'IPL.TO', 'IMI', 'ITH.TO', 'INPH', 'IP.MI', 'IIN', 'NVTA', 'MYPK3.SA', 'IRIX', 'ISDR', 'ITM.MI', 'JACK', 'JMBA', 'JAMN', 'JSDA', 'KD8.DE', 'KBC.BR', 'KMPR', 'KWE.L', 'KE', 'KXS.TO', 'KGX.DE', 'KIPS', 'KCO.DE', 'KOP', 'KTOS', 'KYTH', 'LIF.TO', 'LAMR', 'LMRK', 'LXS.DE', 'LPI', 'LEE', 'LCUT', 'LINX3.SA', 'LGF', 'LQDT', 'LQMT', 'LOJN', 'LPN.BK', 'LRAD', 'MMP', 'MX', 'MAIN', 'MFC.TO', 'MRO', 'MMI', 'MKL', 'MRE.TO', 'MLP', 'MMS', 'MCB.TO', 'MKTY', 'MEG', 'MDVN', 'MPEL', 'MTSL', 'MRK.DE', 'MEO.DE', 'METSB.HE', 'MGEE', 'MGPI', 'KORS', 'MDXG', 'MTX', 'MRTX', 'MNW.TO', 'MBLY', 'MHK', 'TAP', 'MNDI.L', 'MNST', 'MSBF', 'MUV2.DE', 'MVBF', 'MYL', 'NCMI', 'NFG', 'NHC', 'NWLI', 'NGS', 'NRP', 'NAVG', 'NNI', 'NEON', 'NPTN', 'NVC.TO', 'NDRM', 'NVRO', 'NFI.TO', 'NWHM', 'BCI.TO', 'NEWR', 'SNR', 'NYT', 'NAL.TO', 'NXST', 'EGOV', 'NKA', 'NDLS', 'GND.PA', 'NII.TO', 'NORTHM.CO', 'NSAM', 'NRF', 'MIFI', 'NTN', 'NUS', 'NUAN', 'NVDA', 'NXTM', 'OCAT', 'ORIG', 'OGE', 'OHRP', 'OML.L', 'ZEUS', 'OMAM', 'OTIV', 'ONC.TO', 'ONTY', 'ORBC', 'OA', 'OWW', 'OREX', 'OEC', 'ORN', 'ORV.TO', 'OR.TO', 'OUT', 'OSTK', 'PACD', 'PHX', 'PARR', 'PAR', '034230.KQ', 'PGRE', 'PKI.TO', 'P1Z.DE', 'PPL.TO', 'PGF.TO', 'PFLT', 'PSEM', 'PESI', 'PTX', 'PETR4.SA', 'PC.MI', 'PZA.TO', 'PKC1V.HE', 'PLNR', 'PLUG', 'PBCP', 'POPE', 'POST', 'PLPC', 'PBH.TO', 'PBH', 'PRIM', 'PRA', 'PGNX', 'PRO', 'PVCT', 'PRSC', 'QTWO', 'QCCO', 'QTWW', 'QUMU', 'ROIAK', 'RDUS', 'RMR1V.HE', 'RLOG', 'RRS.L', 'RPTP', 'ROLL', 'RCAP', 'RMAX', 'RDI', 'RLYP', 'RGEN', 'RJET', 'REXI', 'RVNC', 'RVLT', 'RWLK', 'RHM.DE', 'RHK.DE', 'RICE', 'RMP', 'RIC.TO', 'RIO.L', 'RSTI', 'RRMS', 'RGLD', 'RSA.L', 'RBCN', '2915.TW', 'SBH', 'SRPT', 'SIS.TO', 'SEAS', 'SEM', 'SEMG', 'SNH', 'SREV', 'SGL.DE', 'SCL.TO', '002327.SZ', 'SSTK', 'MAKRO.BK', 'SW.TO', 'SSO.TO', 'SKUL', 'SMA.TO', 'SPRO', 'SNC.TO', 'SLTD', '300144.SZ', 'SOP.PA', 'SPPI', 'SRC', 'SRLP', 'LEAF', 'SFM', 'JOE', '1565.TWO', 'SAZ.DE', 'STMP', 'STN.TO', 'SWAY', 'SXCL', 'SPLP', 'STEM', 'SLG.V', 'SGM', 'STRT', 'SPH', 'SMLP', 'SUNE', 'SHO', 'SFY', 'SSRG', 'SY1.DE', 'SNTA', 'SYPR', 'TEG.DE', 'TLF', 'TNGO', 'TARO', 'TCP', 'TCPC', 'TCPI', 'TEAR', 'TGLS', 'TGEN', 'TK', 'TGP', 'TOO', 'TNK', 'TIT.MI', 'T.TO', 'TPK.TO', 'TDC', 'TGO.TO', 'TII.V', 'TERP', 'TSRO', 'TESO', 'TXMD', 'TST', 'TCRD', 'TCM.TO', 'TLR', 'TOD.MI', 'TSRE', 'TAT', 'TRXC', 'TLP', 'RIGP', 'TA', 'TREC', 'THS', 'TRMR', 'GTS', 'TRUE', 'TOS.TO', 'TC.TO', 'HEAR', 'TPC', 'TWC.TO', 'USPH', 'UBNT', 'UMH', 'UNI.MI', 'US.MI', 'UVV', 'OLED', 'UEIC', 'UUU', 'UTI', 'USCR', 'USIM5.SA', 'EGY', 'VRNS', 'VEC', 'VER', 'VIAB', 'VSAT', 'VIP', 'PPRO', 'WPP', 'WEW.TO', 'WAIR', 'WEQ.TO', 'WTE.TO', 'WB.TO', 'WWASA.OL', 'WG', 'WIN', 'FUR', 'O1BC.DE', 'XOXO', 'XOMA', 'XDC.TO', 'YORW', 'ZSPH', 'ZURN.VX', 'ZNGA']
```

Comment: can you please explain the `(normalize-space(.)`  I understand the rest of the code perfectly :)

Comment: [`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) _"strips leading and trailing whitespace and replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single space"_. In your use-case, I used it to get rid of potential whitespace before "Earnings Announcements"